# What makes firebase being called realtime one? Difference between firebase and other databases

Tags: firebase

I was reading about firebase and got to know that it is a realtime database to store data. What makes it realtime? Is it that it automatically gets updated with a view/model change whereas in other dbs we force a query to make the changes

Comment: Yes, that is exactly why. Any changes that one client makes to the data in your Firebase, are automatically synchronized to all other connected clients in real-time. So with Firebase your code is *watching* a data structure, instead of querying that data structure.

Comment: Thank you. Got an understanding